# Extracting decimal from time

Tags: excel, vba, variables, time

I have Date and Time in one cell and I need to extract the decimal that excel uses for the time so that I can subtract time from that.

A cell has this value: 01.09.2020 7:01:21
I need to get the time 7:01:21
and then I need to extract the decimal which represents it, that is: 0,292604166666667 and store it in a variable in vba

I searched the internet extensively but everyone wants to do exactly the opposite and I am totally clueless.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I worked it out.

I am not entirely happy with the solution but it works. I am sure some of you guys can come up with a more elegant solution without having to use the variable.

Mine is this:

```
Dim NumericTime as Double
NumericTime = TimeValue("A1")
Debug.Print NumericTime
```

Comment: Be happy with it. It is the solution.

Comment: Function `CDbl` to convert to double, to avoid the intermediate variable.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To extract a decimal, simply:

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

Be sure to format the results as `General` or as `Number` with an appropriate number of decimal places

[image]

In VBA, the `Mod` function doesn't work with decimals, so the equivalent might be:

```
Function DecimalTime(tm As Date) As Double
    DecimalTime = tm - Int(tm)
End Function
```